# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 error occurs at Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

First, my environment is LAMP(M stand for MariaDB).

Whole error is:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 (SQL: UPDATE Demos SET Hit = ifnull(Hit,0) + 1 WHERE id = '27')
```

code in the model is

```
protected function IncreaseHit($id) {
    DB::select('UPDATE Demos SET Hit = ifnull(Hit,0) + 1 WHERE id = \''.$id.'\'');
}
```

What I want to say is this code works well at my local. (local environment is MAMP.)

And code that calls above model method at controller is

```
if(Cookie::get('My_Cookie_'.$id) != 'On'){
    Demos::IncreaseHit($id);
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('CS_View_'.$id, 'On',2160000));
}//Cookie Check
```

I can't find what is wrong... Please let me know how I can fix this error.

Comment: First of all you must use DB::raw(), second - as I know DB::select() only for selecting data

Comment: Thank you for comment. Then what if i want to make my own DB query without Eloquent ORM??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DB::update()`:

```
DB::update('UPDATE Demos SET Hit = ifnull(Hit,0) + 1 WHERE id = ?', [$id]);
```

Also this error is produced when there's nothing to fetch. That way with `DB::select()` you're trying to fetch something from a statement that doesn't return anything.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#running-queries

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::connection('my_conn')->update('UPDATE asterisk.chan_line SET sms_balance = (sms_balance-1) where id = ? ', [$value->id]);
```

Hope it helps.