# MySQL General error after successful insert from view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.4 with PHP 7.2 all within xampp. I am trying to truncate a temporary table and then insert the new data from a MySQL View. The code executes and does exactly what I want it to do, but it says there is an error -

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error (SQL: Insert Into prod_joins_temp
>   (date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id)
>   Select date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id From prod_joins)

Initially I had the following error `General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared` after inserting two columns to my View: a `time_start` and `time_end` column.

I tried deleting the two columns to see if that was the issue, but now all I get in the dreaded general error.

I tried this answer [Laravel: General error: 1615 Prepared statement needs to be re-prepared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34545211/1120276). It didnt work and according to the comments it will cause problem ak validations.

I have found this answer [PDO error: “ SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error ” When updating database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979510/pdo-error-sqlstatehy000-general-error-when-updating-database) which is the exaclty the same issue to my problem, but it doesnt answer my question because I am not using `fetchAll()` nor am I using any duplicated variables of any variables at all.

I have tried two ways of achieving my goal as follows.

**Truncate table prod_joins_temp**

```
ProdJoinsTemp::truncate();
```

**Then populate table prod_joins_temp from the view prod_joins**

```
DB::select('Insert Into prod_joins_temp (date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id) Select date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id From prod_joins');
```

The other way which gives me exactly the same error is as follows

**drop table prod_joins_temp if it exists**

```
\Schema::dropIfExists('prod_joins_temp');
```

**Then create table prod_joins_temp from the view prod_joins**

```
DB::select('CREATE TABLE prod_joins_temp AS SELECT * FROM prod_joins;');
```

Here is the code that makes the view

```
SELECT
    `scorecard54`.`production`.`date` AS `date`,
    `scorecard54`.`products`.`code` AS `code`,
    `scorecard54`.`production`.`sid_production` AS `sid`,
    `scorecard54`.`production`.`time_start` AS `time_start`,
    `scorecard54`.`production`.`time_end` AS `time_end`,
    `scorecard54`.`production`.`made` AS `made`,
    `scorecard54`.`qcontrol`.`firsts` AS `firsts`,
    `scorecard54`.`qcontrol`.`seconds` AS `seconds`,
    `scorecard54`.`production`.`broken_production` AS `p_broken`,
    `scorecard54`.`qcontrol`.`broken_qcontrol` AS `q_broken`,
    `scorecard54`.`grinding`.`discarded` AS `g_broken`,
    `scorecard54`.`products`.`prod_id` AS `prod_id`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                `scorecard54`.`production`
            LEFT JOIN `scorecard54`.`products` ON
                (
                    (
                        `scorecard54`.`production`.`prod_code` = `scorecard54`.`products`.`prod_id`
                    )
                )
            )
        LEFT JOIN `scorecard54`.`grinding` ON
            (
                (
                    `scorecard54`.`production`.`sid_production` = `scorecard54`.`grinding`.`sid_grinding`
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN `scorecard54`.`qcontrol` ON
        (
            (
                `scorecard54`.`grinding`.`tray_id_grinding` = `scorecard54`.`qcontrol`.`tray_id_qcontrol`
            )
        )
    )
WHERE
    (
        `scorecard54`.`grinding`.`have_qcontrol` = 1
    )
```

And here is the function that drops and creates a table from the view

```
public function generateTable(Request $request) {

    // Drop temp table
    \Schema::dropIfExists('prod_joins_temp');

    // re create table with the new data
    DB::select('CREATE TABLE prod_joins_temp AS SELECT * FROM prod_joins;');


    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Success: Reports table regenerated.');
    return Redirect::to('/statistics/');

}
```

I also tried truncating then re-populating with this function

```
public function generateTable(Request $request) {

    // Drop temp table
    ProdJoinsTemp::truncate();

    // re generate table with the new data
    DB::select('Insert Into prod_joins_temp (date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id) Select date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id From prod_joins');   

    $request->session()->flash('alert-success', 'Success: Reports table regenerated.');
    return Redirect::to('/statistics/');

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there some sort of cache for views?

Comment: I got the prepared-statement error when I added time_start and time_end to the view, but when I deleted time_start and time_end I get this new general error. It would seem my code is in exactly the same state it was before the prepared-statement error. I have added my view code and two function I have tried to re populate the temporary table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue from this answer [SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053 error occurs at Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36397281/1120276)

Where before I was updating my table using the following

```
DB::select('Insert Into prod_joins_temp (date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id) Select date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id From prod_joins');
```

I changed the select part of the query to update and it all works fine. please see following

```
DB::update('Insert Into prod_joins_temp (date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id) Select date,code,sid,time_start,time_end,made,firsts,seconds,p_broken,q_broken,g_broken,prod_id From prod_joins');
```

I don't know why the previous way worked before I added fields to my view, but now it requires me to use update instead of select